# Phalcon PhP: how to bind parameters in SQL query inside a Controller

Tags: php, phalcon

I'm trying to run a raw SQL query, inside a Controller class, and I'm having trouble to figure out why I can't bind more than one parameter. Take a look at the snippet below:

```
    $sql = "select
        u.id,
        u.name,
        u.email,
        r.name as role
    from user u
    inner join role r on r.id = u.role_id
    left join user_group_user ugu on ugu.user_id = u.id and ugu.user_group_id = ".$user_group_id."
    where (u.name like :search or u.email like :search or r.name like :search)      
        and ugu.user_id is null and u.id not in( :notIn )
    order by u.name, r.name";

    $users = $this->db->query($sql, ['search' => '%'.$search.'%', 'notIn'=>$notInStr ])->fetchAll();
```

The $`notIn` variable has a value like `1,2,3`. If I do the same thing only with the parameter :search the query works. When I try with both parameters (:search and :notIn) the query returns but the :notIn seems to not have effect in the query. It looks like it is not being bound.

How can I run this query considering both parameters?

Thanks for any help

UPDATE:
The binding is actually working but it is binding the `:notIn` as a string, so the executed query is  `.... not in ('1,2,3')`

I have solved my problem just making sure that everything is a number and just concatenating in the query: `...u.id not in( ".$notInStr." )`

Answer (score 1):

Standard pdo library which phalcon is using and which phalcon db is wrapping doesn't accept array as bound parameter. You would need to use phalcon models.

Answer (score 1):

Make use of `Phalcon\Mvc\Model\Query\Builder`. There is a `inWhere` method, that accepts array as parameter.

Remember to never use not filtered data that You get from end-user, like You just did. This makes Yours application vulnerable to SQLInjection attacks.